# Did suleiman take help from evil jinns?

Tags: jinn, prophet-sulayman

We know suleiman took help of jinns from Quran.

My question is were they evil?

Answer (score 3):

Prophet Solomon didn't take their help, they were made subservient to him by Allah. The Quran mentions that the devils were included:

> [Quran 21:81-82](https://quran.com/21/81-82) And to Solomon [We subjected] the wind, blowing
>   forcefully, proceeding by his command toward the land which We had
>   blessed. And We are ever, of all things, Knowing. **And of the devils**
>   were those who dived for him and did work other than that. And We were
>   of them a guardian.
>
> [Quran 38:36-38](https://quran.com/38/36-38) So We subjected to him the wind blowing by his
>   command, gently, wherever he directed, And [also] **the devils** [of jinn]
>   - every builder and diver. And others bound together in shackles.

Comment: Bringing the throne of balqis? Didn't a qarin or ifreet help him?

Comment: The throne was brought by someone who knew the scripture [27:40](https://quran.com/27/40), I don't think that he would qualify as a devil. Though there are different interpretations about whether he was a jinn or human and I think there is already a question about that on SE.

Comment: Ifreet means a powerful jinn not necessarily a devil

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. My comment that I don't think that the person who brought the throne would be evil was in lieu of the original question. The interpretations on the one who brought the throne are summarized in Medi1Saif's answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35549/20218).

Comment: @AbuAbdulQayyum as Uma mentioned, there is an answer about the throne here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35549/15201